# Trying to write my own Greedy/ Nearest Neighbor Algorithm

Tags: programming, code-request

So I'm trying to write my own function and compare it to the results I have from using FindShortestTour.

Does anyone know how to find the distance from each city to each of the others without tedious code. I have 50 cities and I want to find the distance between all the cities so then I can write a Greedy Algorithm.

I know I have to use GeoDistance but I'm not sure how to do all 50 cities.

These are the cities I have:

{GeoPosition[{18.96, 72.82}], GeoPosition[{12.97, 77.56}], 
 GeoPosition[{27.19, 78.01}], GeoPosition[{19.89, 75.32}], 
 GeoPosition[{24.85, 79.93}], GeoPosition[{32.71, 74.85}], 
 GeoPosition[{15.42, 73.78}], GeoPosition[{26.92, 75.8}], 
 GeoPosition[{24.58, 73.69}], GeoPosition[{26.92, 70.9}], 
 GeoPosition[{34.17, 77.58}], GeoPosition[{32.27, 77.17}], 
 GeoPosition[{31.1033, 77.1722}], GeoPosition[{27.34, 88.61}], 
 GeoPosition[{27.05, 88.26}], GeoPosition[{8.078, 77.541}], 
 GeoPosition[{29.98, 78.16}], GeoPosition[{29.38, 79.45}], 
 GeoPosition[{28.6, 77.22}], GeoPosition[{30.34, 78.05}], 
 GeoPosition[{31.64, 74.87}], GeoPosition[{27.1, 77.67}], 
 GeoPosition[{17.4, 78.48}], GeoPosition[{12.88, 74.84}], 
 GeoPosition[{25.57, 91.87}], GeoPosition[{17.73, 83.3}], 
 GeoPosition[{30.73, 79.07}], GeoPosition[{13.63, 79.41}], 
 GeoPosition[{10.23, 77.48}], GeoPosition[{22.57, 88.36}], 
 GeoPosition[{18.98, 73.27}], GeoPosition[{25.32, 83.01}], 
 GeoPosition[{17.92, 73.67}], GeoPosition[{24.71, 84.98}], 
 GeoPosition[{26.85, 80.92}], GeoPosition[{9.92, 78.12}], 
 GeoPosition[{23.17, 79.94}], GeoPosition[{24.6, 72.7}], 
 GeoPosition[{29.4, 79.12}], GeoPosition[{11.4117, 76.6947}], 
 GeoPosition[{8.51, 76.95}], GeoPosition[{13.09, 80.27}], 
 GeoPosition[{12.3, 76.6}], GeoPosition[{13.21, 75.99}], 
 GeoPosition[{9.61, 77.15}], GeoPosition[{10.08, 77.0597}], 
 GeoPosition[{15.33, 76.46}], GeoPosition[{12.62, 80.1994}], 
 GeoPosition[{26.35, 92.67}], GeoPosition[{11.58, 75.59}]}

Thanks

Comment: This question appear to relate to another one; which "50 cities" are you referring to?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I tried to make a do loop in which I tell the program to look at what the nearest location is and then connect to it, if the nearest location is already a location that has been visited then to go to the next nearest location. 
however, I am unable to connect it to the geoPostitions and geoDistances

Answer (score 2):

If you want the minimal set of distances start with [`Subsets`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subsets.html):

```
cities = {Entity["City", {"Bombay", "Maharashtra", "India"}], 
  Entity["City", {"Bengaluru", "Karnataka", "India"}], 
  Entity["City", {"Agra", "UttarPradesh", "India"}], 
  Entity["City", {"Aurangabad", "Maharashtra", "India"}]};

# -> GeoDistance @@ # & /@ Subsets[cities, {2}]
```

[image]

For a complete set try [`Tuples`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html) or [`Outer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html).
`Outer` produces an extra level of bracketing that may be useful.

```
# -> GeoDistance @@ # & /@ Tuples[cities, {2}]

Outer[{##} -> GeoDistance[##] &, cities, cities]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info! I just put all my GeoPositions in the info. 
Well I'm trying to create an algorithm to find the best route so i would want to know all the distances between each city and then I want it to choose the closest city and continue to iterate

Comment: I got all the distances for the cities. I'm going to write a do loop so it chooses the nearest city

Comment: @Sarah Consider possibly sorting the table, e.g. `dist = Outer[{##} -> GeoDistance[##] &, cities, cities];` then `SortBy[QuantityMagnitude@*Last] /@ dist`