# How do I find the nearest city out of a list of cities?

Tags: programming, code-request

I am trying to find the next closest city to city 1 and want to use a certain radius to check what is the closest city I'm trying to create an algorithm for a TSP. Does anyone know how to implement the GeoDistance feature with a radius feature?

Thanks

```
(* sets all locations equal to cities *)
cities = {GeoPosition[{18.96`, 72.82`}], 
GeoPosition[{12.97`, 77.56`}], GeoPosition[{27.19`, 78.01`}], 
GeoPosition[{19.89`, 75.32000000000001`}], 
GeoPosition[{24.85`, 79.93`}], 
GeoPosition[{32.71`, 74.85000000000001`}], 
GeoPosition[{15.42`, 73.78`}], GeoPosition[{26.92`, 75.8`}], 
GeoPosition[{24.580000000000002`, 73.69`}], 
GeoPosition[{26.92`, 70.9`}], GeoPosition[{34.17`, 77.58`}], 
GeoPosition[{32.27`, 77.17`}], GeoPosition[{31.1033`, 77.1722`}], 
GeoPosition[{27.34`, 88.61`}], GeoPosition[{27.05`, 88.26`}], 
GeoPosition[{8.078`, 77.541`}], GeoPosition[{29.98`, 78.16`}], 
GeoPosition[{29.38`, 79.45`}], GeoPosition[{28.6`, 77.22`}], 
GeoPosition[{30.34`, 78.05`}], GeoPosition[{31.64`, 74.87`}], 
GeoPosition[{27.1`, 77.67`}], 
GeoPosition[{17.400000000000002`, 78.48`}], 
GeoPosition[{12.88`, 74.84`}], GeoPosition[{25.57`, 91.87`}], 
GeoPosition[{17.73`, 83.3`}], 
GeoPosition[{30.73`, 79.07000000000001`}], 
GeoPosition[{13.63`, 79.41`}], GeoPosition[{10.23`, 77.48`}], 
GeoPosition[{22.57`, 88.36`}], GeoPosition[{18.98`, 73.27`}], 
GeoPosition[{25.32`, 83.01`}], GeoPosition[{17.92`, 73.67`}], 
GeoPosition[{24.71`, 84.98`}], GeoPosition[{26.85`, 80.92`}], 
GeoPosition[{9.92`, 78.12`}], GeoPosition[{23.17`, 79.94`}], 
GeoPosition[{24.6`, 72.7`}], 
GeoPosition[{29.400000000000002`, 79.12`}], 
GeoPosition[{11.411746`, 76.69466`}], GeoPosition[{8.51`, 76.95`}],
GeoPosition[{13.09`, 80.27`}], GeoPosition[{12.3, 76.6}], 
GeoPosition[{13.21, 75.99}], GeoPosition[{9.61, 77.15}], 
GeoPosition[{10.08, 77.0597}], GeoPosition[{15.33, 76.46}], 
GeoPosition[{12.62, 80.1994}], GeoPosition[{26.35, 92.67}], 
GeoPosition[{11.58, 75.59}]};
```

Comment: Try `GeoNearest["City", origin, {1, distance}]`.  Or, if you have a list of cities you want to search, `GeoNearest[list, origin, {1, distance}]`

Comment: Use `GeoPosition` on your list of cities as input to `Nearest`, to get a `NearestFunction`. You can then apply that to individual cities to get neighbors within some radius.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I already have my cites in GeoPosition 
could you show me an example?

Comment: @Sarah do you want to find the closest city, or whether a city exists within a certain radius as your title suggests?

Comment: @2012rcampion I have a list of cities and I want to search through them and find the closest city. And then after I visit the next city, I want to take it out of the search.

Comment: I've modified my answer to match that spec.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [(80488)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/80488/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard They're definitely about the same thing, but I don't think they're duplicates.  That one asked about finding all distances, this one is about finding the nearest point.

Comment: @Sarah Can you edit your question to clarify for people in the future that this question is about looking for the nearest city, not a city within a specified distance?

Comment: @2012rcampion I changed it, thanks for all the help.

Comment: Here we create a `NearestFunction`. `In[52]:= nf = Nearest[cities];` Now use it to find the two closest ones to the fourth entry.
`Rest[nf[cities[[4]], 3]]

Out[53]= {GeoPosition[{18.98, 73.27}], GeoPosition[{17.92, 73.67}]}`

Answer (score 3):

First we define the city to search from:

```
city1 = Entity["City", {"Champaign", "Illinois", "UnitedStates"}];
```

(You can enter the `Entity` object by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> champaign <kbd>Enter</kbd>.)

We then search for the nearest city using `GeoNearest`:

```
GeoNearest["City", city1, {1, Quantity[10, "Kilometers"]}]
```

The option `1` means that we should return at most 1 match.

Of course, the return value in this case is simply:

```
{Entity["City", {"Champaign", "Illinois", "UnitedStates"}]}
```

That is, the closest city to Champaign is Champaign. D'oh!  We can fix this by excluding `city1` explicitly:

```
GeoNearest[Except[city1, "City"], city1, 1]
```

The output is now:

```
{Entity["City", {"Savoy", "Illinois", "UnitedStates"}]}
```

(If we don't put `1` we get both Savoy and Urbana, since they both touch Champaign and their distance is zero.)

If you have a specific list of cities you want to search through, we can specify that list instead of `"City"`:

```
cityList = GeoEntities[Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Virginia", "UnitedStates"}], "City"];
GeoNearest[cityList, city1, 1]
```

This simply returns `{Entity["City", {"Ewing", "Virginia", "UnitedStates"}]}`.

Comment: What if I want to exclude the first city? Do you do the similar except command you did earlier?

Comment: You can use `DeleteCases[cityList, city1]`.  I don't think the `Except` query syntax will work with a list.

Comment: Within my CityList, do I have to go through each GeoPosition and define it as City1, City2,.... etc. ?

Comment: I got it to work ,once I defined city 1.

GeoNearest[DeleteCases[CityList, city1], city1, 1]

thanks, now I have to create a loop so it iterates and finds the nearest city to the city that was nearest to city 1.

Comment: @Sarah In this case I put the city you are searching from into a seprate variable, `city1`.  If, for example, you want to find the nearest city to the first one in `CityList`, you'd do something like `GeoNearest[Rest[CityList], First[CityList]]`.  The specifics of how you handle this list manipulation are out of scope for this question.